# Powershell Transcript is failing to write file

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

In export it's not taking `$output` as a file name, and in Verbose mode when I am checking, it is successfully generating the file but it is not being populated on the location.

And on the second place in mailbox export whenever I am trying to use `$output.pst` it is giving me an error.

```
#Export output Trace
Add-PSSnapin *exchange*
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
#$date = Get-Date -format MM:dd:yyyy
$mailboxes = Get-Content D:\export\mailbox1.txt
$output = $mailboxes + "@" + $date
#Start-Transcript -Path D:\export\$output.txt
#start-transcript -path D:\export\$(get-date -format 'MMddyyyy') ("&") $output.txt 
#start-transcript -path C:\$(get-date -format 'MMddyyyy')$output.txt -Force
#Start-Transcript | Select Path -OutVariable d:\export\$output
Write-Host "$output export is in pogress"
#Stop-Transcript
#Invoke-Item $output.Path
foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes)
{  
Write-Host "$output export is in pogress"
(new-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $mailboxes -batchname $mailboxes -FilePath \\MX01\export\$output.pst -BadItemLimit 50 |fl)
#time to wait for completing mailbox export
Start-Sleep -Verbose -Seconds 10
(Get-MailboxExportRequest -BatchName $mailboxes |fl)
#Start-Sleep -Verbose -Seconds 3
#(Get-MailboxExportRequest -BatchName $mailboxes |fl)
}
```

Comment: What does `D:\export\mailbox1.txt` contain? A single line or multiple lines?

Comment: Solved it anyways